# After updating my terminal it's showing bash 5.2. what should i do?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

After updating my terminal it's showing bash 5.2 on my terminal. new user like me going to  confuse. bash 5.2 "cd downlode there is no
such file like this"

[image: bash.5.2]

Comment: There are no OS/product/release details; how will this help anyone?  There is little context to explain the problem or issue

Answer (score 0):

1. First go to shell menu and go to *Preferences* settings.
2. Go to *Profile* and click on the *Command* tab and then in command click on *Run command as a login shell* and finish.
   [image: login shell]